# Angular subscribe is deprecated

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am having a problem with angular. I am new to it and was following the guide from this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dT1ID4q57fs&list=PLXKzVP4cRi8A4G6vnFB5bKpAStskhFwG0&index=3
At around the 12 minute mark when he adds the subscribe function and adds response and error, my subscribe function gets striked eg: <s>subscribe</s>

This is my code for home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Breakpoints, BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { CursorError } from '@angular/compiler/src/ml_parser/lexer';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  /** Based on the screen size, switch from standard to one column per row */
  cards:any = [];
  cardsForHandset:any = [];
  cardsForWeb:any = [];

  isHandset: boolean = false;
  isHandsetObserver: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset).pipe(
    map(({ matches }) => {
      if (matches) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    })
  );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
    public appService:AppService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.isHandsetObserver.subscribe(currentObserverValue => {
      this.isHandset = currentObserverValue;
      this.loadCards();
    });

    this.appService.getDeals().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.cardsForHandset = response.handsetCards;
        this.cardsForWeb = response.webCards;
        this.loadCards();
      },
      error => {
        alert('There was an error in retrieving data from the server');
      }
    );
  }


  loadCards(){
    this.cards = this.isHandset? this.cardsForHandset:this.cardsForWeb;
  }

}
```

[This is the message it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Dnd.png)

I saw some solutions saying its the version of typescript but changing those didn't fix it.
I'm on windows using vs code, but it works for my friends using ubuntu.
This is the version when I type ng --version:

```
Angular CLI: 13.2.6
Node: 16.14.0
Package Manager: npm 8.3.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: undefined
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1302.6 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         13.2.6 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   13.2.6 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          13.2.6 (cli-only)
rxjs                         6.6.7
typescript                   4.6.2
```

Any solution would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Did you check the [deprecations](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments) page? There they have given examples of how to use as well?

Comment: All signatures of subscribe that take more than 1 argument is deprecated. See https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments for more information

Comment: Now mostly you have to do... `.subscribe({ success: () => {...}, error: () => {...}, complete: () => {...}`. Instead of 3 parameters, now you have to pass an `object` having upto 3 keys(informally stating), namely `success`, `error` and `complete`...

Answer (score 8):

For example, in above case, instead of writing this...

```ts
this.isHandsetObserver.subscribe(currentObserverValue => {
      this.isHandset = currentObserverValue;
      this.loadCards();
    });

    this.appService.getDeals().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.cardsForHandset = response.handsetCards;
        this.cardsForWeb = response.webCards;
        this.loadCards();
      },
      error => {
        alert('There was an error in retrieving data from the server');
      }
    );
```

we will be writing...

```ts
this.isHandsetObserver.subscribe({
    next: (currentObserverValue) => {
        this.isHandset = currentObserverValue;
        this.loadCards();
    }
});

this.appService.getDeals().subscribe({
    next: (response) => {
        this.cardsForHandset = response.handsetCards;
        this.cardsForWeb = response.webCards;
        this.loadCards();
    },
    error: (error) => {
        alert('There was an error in retrieving data from the server');
    }
});
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me but my friend that was writing on ubuntu sent me his code (which is exactly the same as mine) and it works.
The only difference is that his version of typescript is 4.5.5. and angular devkit and schematics are not cli-only (like they are in my build). Hope that helps anyone who might have the same problem as me.
And thank you for your help :)

Comment: Nalin the notifications and therefore the properties for the observer are `next`, `error` and `complete`. So in your answer you need to change the properties `success:` of the observers with `next:`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @akotech. Updated. Indeed silly on my part.

Answer (score 1):

There are Limitations of the subscribe error handler, there are a few more operators that allow us to implement more advanced error handling strategies.

```
this.appService.getDeals()
        .pipe(
            catchError(err => of([]))
        )
        .subscribe({
            next: (response) => {
                this.cardsForHandset = response.handsetCards;
                this.cardsForWeb = response.webCards;
                this.loadCards();
            },
            error: (err) => {
                 alert('There was an error in retrieving data from the server');
            }
        });
```

reference included [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/)